# Get root privileges for nautilus on sftp connection

Tags: nautilus, ssh, root, sftp

I use "Connect to server" option to sftp to remote computers, as a user which has sudoer privileges. But then, I cannot get root privileges to modify system files. How can I do this?

(I know i can use ssh and then use sudo, but I was wondering if there's a quicker method.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hya, bad news for you. The short answer is that you can't — you get the privileges of the user you logged in as.

The long answer follows herewith… The 'connect to server' option is nothing but a pretty gui that issues simple sftp commands under the hood, once connected to a server via an ssh like transport protocol. A list of these commands is available if you enter a terminal window and enter `man sftp`. You'll see the commands available to 'connect to server' in the section 'interactive commands' of the manpage.

They are limited to `bye cd chgrp chmod chown df exit get help lcd lls lmkdir ln lpwd ls lumask mkdir progress put pwd quite rename rm rmdir symlink` and `!`. You may recognise many of them from ftp, if you ever command-line ftp'd. Some new cool additions, but as you can see none of them supports the concept of RunAs, or `sudo`.

Gaining elevated privileges was simply never designed into the protocol.

Comment: such a bad news to me as well :( Is there any alternate to this. As recommended I always keep the root login disabled in my sshd_config.